# mysql_real_escape_string() does not work properly?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to make the users profile public or private and I have coded something in PHP.
But I am getting following error:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'gooyanet'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on line 7
```

And also:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established on line 7
```

Here is a link to [*my code*](http://www.paste.org/75963).

It would be great if you help me with that ...

Comment: It's nothing to do with `mysql_real_escape_string`, your MySQL login credentials are incorrect or your user doesn't have permission on that database.

Comment: It's because you haven't got a working database connection configured.

Comment: The problem could indeed be with your connection credentials, please check them. And do stop using mysql_real_escape_string, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  A modern API has better ways to [deal with SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) than real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you havnt provided the code the problem may be due to the connection credentials given in your code.

The use of `mysql_real_escape_string()` is depreciated.Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and stay safe from sql injection.